# How to create an interface which shows the objects in left side and detail for each object in the right side?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jtextpane, jsplitpane

I'm not sure which container or component can help to create the following menu bar. I already created the menu bar and status bar at the bottom. But I have no idea which interface is the best.

[image]

I apprecite any help,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- put [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) to the left side
- put [JTextArea, better JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) to the right area
- put both (`JList` and `JTextArea/JTextPane`) [JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) to the [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm curios what's the best container for the area? I meant JList sits on panel?

Comment: there are two ways put `1)` `JScrollPane contains `JList` (by using pre impemented `BorderLayout`) and  `JScrollPane` contains `JTextArea/JTextPane` directly to the `JFrame` `2)` or to put `JSplitPane` to the `JFrame` with `JScrollPane` contains `JList`  and second `JScrollPane` contains `JTextArea/JTextPane`

Answer (score 4):

The core content (the part in the middle) is using currently using a `JSplitPane`

You can get similar look using a `BorderLayout` (on something like) a `JPanel`.  You'd place the index in a `JScrollPane` down the `WEST` side of the container and the `Details` pane in the `CENTER`

You might also find a `CardLayout` useful you need to switch panes from the content area

Comment: You probably do not need to switch panes from the content area. Just update the contents (e.g. a panel which can show the properties of the album, on which you can set the album which in turn updates the values of the UI -> the album is the "model" for that panel)